# Lots of sshd processes on my gitlab server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab, openssh

System: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Git version 2.1.3

There lots of sshd processes like below

```
git      31845 31674  0 17:05 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      31897 31829  0 15:34 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      31910 31744  0 15:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32090 31968  0 16:48 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32160 31974  0 16:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32165 32014  0 16:48 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32253 32043  0 15:55 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32279 32118  0 16:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32484 32317  0 17:05 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32488 32260  0 15:13 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32530 32403  0 15:34 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32539 32380  0 16:49 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32541 32482  0 17:05 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32570 32499  0 15:34 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32588 32487  0 16:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32612 32566  0 17:05 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32735 32672  0 15:55 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
git      32748 32644  0 16:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
```

those sshd processes`s parent process like below

```
root     32672  9010  0 15:55 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git [priv]
git      6206 32672  0 15:55 ?        00:00:00 sshd: git@notty
```

and more important it will `disappear` after `2 hours`, here is its strace, before it closed , it do nothing

```
root@gitserver:/var/log# strace -p 6206
Process 6206 attached
select(12, [3 5], [], NULL, NULL)       = 1 (in [3])
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
read(3, 0x7fffc95039c0, 16384)          = -1 ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
exit_group(255)                         = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

what happened to my gitlab and why those sshd precesses does not close even if it do nothing ,and closed after exactly `2 hours` ?

Thinks

Comment: Is your SSH server running on a default port?

Comment: @Jonnerz yeah, on port 22, but it never happened before

Comment: Could be some sort of brute force?

Comment: @Jonnerz this problem still there , but I add a item in `sshd_config`  : `  ClientAliveInterval 300` to make the cilent close after 5 mins no responding.